# How to Actually Disable Browser Cache

Tags: caching, browser

Im wondering, how to *actually* disable client cache?

This may seem like a repeat question, but with web browsers constantly changing and evolving over time, Im not confident all of them (or any of them) actually behave as expected when caching features are deactivated.

Over the last 7-8 years developing web applications, Ive constantly run into issues where I have caching disabled in a browser, only to find it is indeed caching javascript resources (or css). I have Shift+F5 (or shift refresh / ctrl + shift + r) permanently burned into my hands as a reflex for refreshing a page to such a degree that it requires active thought on my part to not-refresh the page that way. I shift+refresh even when Im casually browsing (not working)! Still, I dont believe this is always doing what I expect it to do.

I have all of the caching features set to off in Chrome for example. I still constantly run into resources being cached (javascript), to such a degree that I dont even use Chrome as a tool to develop with anymore. As others have observed, Safari's options to clear cache can still return cached data after a refresh. Firefox is rather inconsistent in its caching behaviors between versions. Firebug for Firefox also sometimes returns stale resources. The ONLY tool that I have ever found to actually clear cache is the "Disable Cache" option with the Firefox web developer toolkit plugin.

Why is this? Why is it that I can spend an hour constantly making changes and pressing shift+f5 to observe them, only to be confused as to why my changes dont take hold? Naturally the allegedly-inactive cache always ends up expiring when I ask a colleague for help!

Most of the time, a browser's caching features will work as expected with page content. For example, if I have all the caching features disabled in Chrome or Firefox, the content of an rss feed, or a web page, etc, will always be returned fresh and uncached. Resources like CSS/JS are still often returned stale. I work in Mac OSX, Ubuntu Linux, and MS Windows environments, and work with PHP and Ruby/Rails mostly, and pretty much just use FF/Chrome though occasionally I have to use Safari (and I only ever touch something gross like Internet Explorer when forced). Regardless, this disable-caching issue persists everywhere for me. I feel like I am forced to develop only in Firefox with the web developer toolkit set to disable all cache.

Could anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Im totally willing to accept that "browsers are updated at a rapid ("agile") pace these days, and developers dont make every detail of the preferences UX a top priority, nor is it a priority to expose all of the myriad of additional cache related settings each individual browser has"

Comment: Chrome has a "disable cache while devtools are open" checkbox in the inspector settings. Barring that, add a revision ID, random number or timestamp to the end of every URL. The URL to StackOverflow's favicon, for example, is `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830`.